# What's wrong with my sql connection?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I've created a web service to connect my android device to a mysql database. I made the web service in java using eclipse galileo. I know the web service is working well because I can get my method to return a string so, the only possible problem is with my sql query:

```
      public String getUsers()
```

{

```
        String username = "root";

        String password = "ticket";

        String tablename = "users";

        String fieldname = "*";

                    String query = "SELECT " + fieldname + " FROM " + "android." + tablename + ";";

        /* this chnk of code can appear more or less verbatim */
        /* in your database apps (including JSPs) */
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://"my IP address":3306/android";

        try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()){

        }
        rs.close();

        stmt.close();

        con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        return test;
        }
```

Through debugging: I've narrowed the fail point down to :

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

But, I can't figure out why I am getting the error.

I know my "mysql username and password is correct": I got my url from eclipse's database development perspective when I created the connection. Yes, I have tried switching from my IP address to "localhost" and vice versa. It's been a few hours now, and maybe I just need a fresh set of eyes. Any ideas would be much appreaciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "android" is the name of my database.

Comment: You haven't said what exception you're getting.

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I returned the exception to my android application and the error I got at this point in time was "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" for my driver class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, then you have to be sure that you put your MySQL driver on the class path of your web service implemenation. In Eclipse, this can be done quite easily (I can't tell you how exactly, as I do not know your exact setup). Try googling `eclipse classpath`...

Comment: Then you are saying the my string for declaring of the class is correct though?

Comment: Yes `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is the correct MySQL driver, and the rest of your code looks correct too...

Comment: Thanks, I've just re-added the jar to my class-path. I think I may have added the wrong jar before. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I am still getting the same errors.. Steps to add jar: right click project, build build path: configure build path: add external jar. The jar that I'm using is: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 
any ideas?

Comment: Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
I dont have the full stack trace

Comment: If you know a quick way to get the full stack trace: I would be more then happy to comply.

Comment: For anyone who reads this later: I moved my jar to my WebContent>Webinf>lib folder and I got past the class error. Now it is informing me: message from server: "host" mypcname is not allowed to access this database. Any Ideas?